# C# Convert string variable to FormattableString

Tags: c#, string-formatting, formattablestring

Suppose, in a C# program, I have the following lines in my `app.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="FormattedString" value="{greeting}, {name}." />
</appSettings>
```

And, in my code, I am using it as follows:

```
    private void doStuff()
    {
        var toBeFormatted = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FormattedString"];
        string greeting = @"Hi There";
        string name = @"Bob";
    }
```

And I would like to use the `toBeFormatted` variable as a `FormattableString` to be able to insert the variables via string interpolation - Something along the lines of:

```
Console.WriteLine(toBeFormatted);
```

I've tried things such as:

```
var toBeFormatted = $ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FormattedString"];
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine($toBeFormatted);
```

But both are causing errors. Is there a way to let the compiler know the `toBeFormatted` string should be used as a `FormattableString`?

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874172/dynamic-string-interpolation

Comment: Obviously, no. I say "obviously" because, well, the compiler would need to *compile the replacement expressions at runtime*, which I suppose is *possible*, but it would be really awkward and inefficient. Also consider the horrors of `{MySuperDangerousMethodThatFormatsYourHardDriveAndReturnsAnInt()}`.

Comment: Thanks, @EhsanSajjad - Sad, it would be a cool addition, but makes sense.

Comment: LOL @JeroenMostert - Good point. I guess I just didn't understand how interpolated string worked. Makes sense now, though.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the `FormattableStringFactory.Create` can do some of the job of the compiler, but I still can't get it to evaluate property expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in case it doesn't I suggest the following simple solution:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="FormattedString" value="{0}, {1}." />
</appSettings>
```

then in your code:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(toBeFormatted,greeting, name));
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I knew of this one, I was just hoping there was still a way to use string interpolation over `String.Format`. Thanks!!

Comment: @JohnBustos interpolation is compile time thing, it needs those placeholder available so i think you can't use it via config