# Using DynamicExpression.ParseLambda with string interpolation

Tags: c#, dynamic-expression

I am struggling with DynamicExpression.ParseLambda and string-interpolation

The following ParseLambda fails on the $ character.
Can anyone see why?

```
private static void Main()
{
    var result = ExecuteJob("parameter.Trim()", "    TheVale");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

static string ExecuteJob(string job, string parameter)
{
    //var result = new Func<string, string>(j => $"{parameter.Trim()}");
    //return result(parameter);

    var expression = $"$\"{{{job}}}\"";
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), nameof(parameter));
    var e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, typeof(string), expression);
    return (e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(parameter) ?? "").ToString();
}
```

Comment: If `job` is the string `123`, then `$"$\"{{{job}}}\""` evaluates to the string `$"{123}"`, but there is no variable in your expression named `123`.

Comment: What if you use just `var expression = $"{job}";`. It works, but I don't know if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: `DynamicExpression` does not support string interpolation. Nor, as the comments point out, is that a meaningful feature to add. If you were trying to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39900731/4137916), the fact that it uses `Regex.Replace` is vital for this to work -- that's the thing that's doing the actual "interpolating" (and it doesn't use `$`). But as written you don't actually need any string interpolation, you just want to evaluate `job` as a lambda body and pass it `parameter`.

Comment: You are correct Jeroen I was trying to build on that answer. Disappointing that string concatenation is not supported. Thanks