# c#: deserializing a JSON containing a local property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I deserialize a JSON which looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "FF478946-8536-4295-AC58-F6C3D2B4E5CC",
    "title": "This is a Title with an escaped variable: {VariableName}",
    "weight": 50
}
```

To a corresponding object using Newtonsoft:

```
public class Event
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

And then I want to print the string *Title* which refers to a local string property in code. `VariableName`

```
private string VariableName { get; set; }
private Event CurrentEvent { get; set; }

public void OnNextEventClicked()
{
   Log(CurrentEvent.Title);
}
```

I tried to somehow escape the variable with different approaches like backslash (`"title": "This is a Title with an escaped variable: \"VariableName\""`) or curly brackets like in the code above but i failed... C# always treats the escaped variable as a normal part of the *Title* string.

What's the best way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why not to add `variableName` to your JSON as a parameter?

Comment: Because there are also a lot of deserialized `Event` instances which do not need to reference a local property at all. And others which need to reference completely different local properties. (So imagine you got not only `VariableName` but also `VariableName1`, `VariableName2` and so on.) So writing own classes for possible combination becomes too big an overhead...

Comment: Then, use answers to the question you have duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874172/dynamic-string-interpolation

Comment: Yeah this does the job! Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [@Roman Ryzhiy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63884260/c-deserializing-a-json-containing-a-local-property/63885149#comment112968261_63884260) pointed out in the comments, there is already a good threat about [dynamic string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874172/dynamic-string-interpolation).

The perfect solution for me was the following based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54031466/9338683).

A helper method using *System.Linq.Dynamic*:

```
public string ReplaceMacro(string value, object @object)
{
    return Regex.Replace(value, @"{(.+?)}", 
    match => {
        var p = Expression.Parameter(@object.GetType(), @object.GetType().Name);                
        var e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, match.Groups[1].Value);
        return (e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(@object) ?? "").ToString();
    });
}
```

My full solution:

*JSON:*

```
{
"id": "FF478946-8536-4295-AC58-F6C3D2B4E5CC",
"title": "This is a Title with an escaped variable: {TitleReplacement.VariableName}",
"weight": 50
}
```

*C#:*

Data Class:

```
public class Event
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Class with replacement string:

```
public class TitleReplacement
{
    public string VariableName { get; set; }
}
```

Call it like:

```
private Event CurrentEvent { get; set; }
private TitleReplacement Replacement { get; set; }

public void OnNextEventClicked()
{
    Log(ReplaceMacro(CurrentEvent.Title, Replacement);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you need is just a `string.Replace()`. You may using `nameof()` to get the name of your variable name in string:

```cs
private string VariableName { get; set; }
private Event CurrentEvent { get; set; }

public void OnNextEventClicked()
{
    var message = (CurrentEvent.Title).Replace(
        "{" + nameof(VariableName) + "}", 
        VariableName
    );
    Log(message);
}
```